# If Pattern matched in 1st line i need to remove the 4th line

Tags: regex, perl, vim, sed

Friends,

I need some help in regex pattern match and replace

I usually use `%s/findstring/replacestring/g` for the pattern match and replace in same line

But if my file is some thing like this

```
<tracker xid="tracker4795">
<title>MIC-DMI Change Requests</title>
<description>New tracker created </description>
<dateCreated>2010-05-03 15:18:10 EST</dateCreated>
<displayLines>1</displayLines>
<isRequired>false</isRequired>
```

I need to pattern match the `<tracker xid.*>` and escape all the lines until it match `<displayLine.*>` again if these match both the pattern i need to remove the
`<isRequired>.*`

Something like if pattern matched in both 4th and 6th line remove the 7th line 
Kindly throw some light on how to achieve this

Comment: I do not fully understand your question but why not loop over your input, use something like `$found = 1 if ($line =~ m/findstring/);` to check if a line has the needed string and do whatever you need to do depending on whether `$found` is set.

Comment: Is this file actually XML? If so, parse as XML, and don't try and regexp it.

Comment: Are you looking for `<tracker xid.*>` anywhere in the file, or only in the first line? After that, do you want to remove the first instance of `<isRequired>.*`, or all of them?

Comment: If you can give a more detailed example of your source and expected output, I can give a perl example which parses as XML.

Answer (score 1):

You have to match the entire set of lines. For that, note that `.` does *not* match a newline character; this must be explicitly specified via `\n`. With that, you have multiple options:

#### Match the entire block, use capture groups to excise the line

The pattern is more complex, but this is the general approach:

```
:%s/\(<tracker xid=.*\n\%(.*\n\)\{3}<displayLines>.*\n\)<isRequired.*\n/\1/g
```

#### Match the minimal block, delete separately

This just establishes a match via `:global`, then uses relative addressing to remove the line.

```
:g/<tracker xid=.*\n\%(.*\n\)\{3}<displayLines>.*/+5delete
```

### Caveats

Only do this if you are absolutely sure that the XML source is in a consistent, well-known format. Text editors / regular expressions are a quick and ready tool for this, but fundamentally are the *wrong* tool. Be aware of this, and don't blame the tool when something goes wrong. [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) **For production-grade reliability and automation, please use an XML tool (like *XSL transformations*).**

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'something like this' it *looks* like what you've got there is XML.  I can't say for sure, because 'something like this' covers a lot of defects.

However if it *is* XML, it's a really bad idea to try and parse it with a regular expression. The reason being that XML is a defined data format with a quite strict specification. If everyone sticks to that spec, then all is fine and dandy.

However, if someone is *assuming* you will handle their XML as XML, and you're not (because you're using a regular expression), what you will be creating is a brittle piece of code that at some point in the future will just randomly break for no apparent reason - because they stuck to the XML spec, but changed something in an entirely valid way.

So assuming that it is XML, and looks 'something like' the example below - I would suggest using Perl and [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) to parse your data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml;
{ local $/; $xml = <DATA> };

my $data = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented' )->parse($xml);

foreach my $element ( $data->root->children('tracker') ) {
    my $xid = $element->att('xid');
    print $xid, "\n";
    foreach my $subelement ( $element->children ) {
        if ( $subelement->name eq 'isRequired' ) {

            #delete the 'isRequired' line
            $subelement->delete;
        }
    }

}

$data->print;


__DATA__
<xml>
<tracker xid="tracker4795">
<title>MIC-DMI Change Requests</title>
<description>New tracker created </description>
<dateCreated>2010-05-03 15:18:10 EST</dateCreated>
<displayLines>1</displayLines>
<isRequired>false</isRequired>
</tracker>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the input is in the example format (with only one open-tag per line, and all tracker tags contain a displaylines and isrequired tag), or you can force it to that format, then I think a search-and-replace is too unwieldy, and full XML parsing is "correct" but way more complicated than you need, and you should try a simpler method with the `:g` command:

```
:g#<tracker xid#/<displayLine/d
```

This just searches for lines matching "<tracker xid", then deletes the next line after that matching "<displayLine"

Thus you don't need a specific number of lines in between "<tracker" and "<displayLine" so it is more robust to variances in line offsets, but it is still quite fragile to format changes.

**However**, I repeat the warnings from others: if the format is not easily and consistently predictable then I'd suggest parsing the file line by line in a loop, or using a real XML parser (possibly using Vim's Perl or Python integration), rather than using an `:s` or `:g` command.